# By default, how much do ^ and _ raise and lower the text box in superscript and subscript respectively?

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

I'm trying to define a set of commands for superscript and subscript, but cannot use the characters `^` and `_` in doing so. I've been able to define the correct font size by using `\check@mathfonts\fontsize\sf@size\z@\math@fontsfalse\selectfont`, but can not work out the default values for how much the text box is raised and lowered.

How does TeX/LaTeX define these values?

Comment: it depends on several of the math font dimen parameters and is not a simple formula the amount a superscript is raised depends on the size of the superscript, whether there is subscript, the size of the subscript, and the size of the base. see appendix G of the texbook. If the character `^` is not available `\sp` should give access to the same functionality

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Make that an answer, please.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I'd guess there are much simpler ways to do whatever you are trying to accomplish...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The algorithm for placing sub- and superscripts is "hard-wired" in the TeX engine, and it's not as simple as you might think. First of all, there's a special treatment for sub- and superscripts of "simple characters" like `a`, `\alpha` or `\mathcal{A}`. In this case you also have some *horizontal* displacement of the subscript that is determined by the italic correction of the character: for example, the subscript should be shifted to the left for an `F`, but not for an `A`.

The default values for raising and lowering are as follows in the case of "simple characters". The **superscript** is (tentatively!) raised by the maximum of `(depth of superscript) + (1/4 of the x-height)` and `σk`, where the x-height is the `\fontdimen` parameter number 5, and `σk` is `\fontdimen` parameter number k (of `\textfont2` unless the whole formula is in a sub- or superscript itself). Now it depends on the current style (which, unfortunately, the TeX user can only access via `\mathpalette` or  `\mathchoice`): In `\displaystyle` k=13 is used, in "cramped style" k=15, and k=14 otherwise.

How much the **subscript** is lowered depends on the presence of a superscript. If there's a superscript, then the subscript is (tentatively!) lowered by `σ17`, otherwise by the maximum of `(height of subscript) - (80% of the x-height)` and `σ16`. In the case of a sub- and superscript combination there's an additional adjustment (with some unpleasant side effects), see e.g. [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89442).

If the sub- or superscript is *not* attached to a "simple character" but to some other nucleus, then additional minimum shift values are used: the superscript is raised by at least `(height of nucleus) - σ18`, the subscript is lowered by at least `(depth of nucleus) + σ19`, where `σ18` and `σ19` are to be taken from `\scriptfont2` unless the whole formula is in a sub- or superscript itself (in which case `\scriptscriptfont2` should be used).

I'm not sure if you really want to implement this ... if you do, have a look at Rule 18 of Appendix G in the TeXbook for details.

Answer (score 3):

There is a TUGboat paper titled [Understanding the aesthetics of math typesetting](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/math-support/vieth2008.pdf) with all the details of the typesetting algorithm as well as visual representation of all the parameters. A second paper [Appendix G illuminated](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb27-1/tb86jackowski.pdf) has also a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 1):

TeX doesn't care which specific characters are used to enter a super- or a subscript; it only looks at the catcodes.  So if you can't use `^` and `_` for some reason, assign another character their catcodes...

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\.=7 % superscript
\gdef\superscript#1#2{{#1}.{#2}}
\catcode`\.=8 % subscript
\gdef\subscript#1#2{{#1}.{#2}}
\endgroup

$\superscript{x}{2}$ $\subscript{x}{2}$
\bye
```

It is perhaps unfortunate that there are no primitive control sequences that duplicate the effects of characters with catcodes 3, 4, 7, and 8 (`&`, `$`, `^`, and `_` in plain TeX), but that's the way it was done back in 1982 and now we're stuck with it.