# Consistent vertical positioning of superscripts

Tags: math-mode, positioning, subscripts, superscripts

This is somehow a follow-up question to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110214/4998).

I've got the following math expression:
`\nabla_y u_0^{(i)}\nabla_y v^{(i)}`

However, no matte, whether I enclose the `v` in curly brackets or not (as indirectly suggested in the linked question), the last superscript (`(i)`) is always on a lower vertical position than the first superscript (`(i)`).

What is the optimal and advised method for ensuring that the superscripts are always on the same vertical position throughout my whole document?

---

**Edit**
Thank's to karlkoeller's anwser, I ended up using two custom commands:

```
\newcommand{\supp}[1]{_{\vphantom{0}}^{#1}}
\newcommand{\subp}[2]{_{\vphantom{0}#1}^{#2}}
```

The first is used when no *sub*-script should be printed and the latter is used for all combinations of super- and subscripts. E.g.

```
u\subp{\varepsilon}{(i)} \nabla v\supp{(i)}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because the first term has a subscript and the latter not.

One solution is to put a "phantom" subscript in the second term:

```
\(\nabla_y u_0^{(i)}\nabla_y v_{\phantom{0}}^{(i)}\)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I only have to write a macro for automatically adding that phantom subscript.

Comment: Something like `\newcommand{\pha}[1]{_{\phantom{#1}}}` if you want to specify the subscript: `\pha{0}` or something like `\newcommand{\pha}{_{\phantom{0}}}` if you don't want to specify the subscript: `\pha`

Comment: Ok, a last little follow-up question: How can I ensure, that the subscript `\varepsilon` has the same hight as a number as `0`? When using `\varepsilon` as a subscript, the superscript is still as low as without a phantom-subscript.

Comment: I can not confirm this, the superscripts have all the same height.

Comment: I didn't meant the height of the _super_scripts, but the **sub**scripts. The number `0` has the same hight as `\phantom{0}`. Anyway, I fixed this problem by using `\vphantom{0}` for all subscripts. This ensures a consistent hight of the subscripts and consistent vertical positioning of the superscripts.

Comment: i'm not sure it matters, but the pre-script "y" doesn't have the same baseline as the subscript "0".  (however, the two pre-scripts are even with one another, which is surely more important.)

Comment: pre-script? `y` is a subscript of `\nabla`. I just altered `\nabla_y` into `\nabla_{\!y}` in my document to reduce the space between the symbol and its subscript.