# How can I move the superscript higher?

Tags: tables, math-mode, fontsize, superscripts

I have a code like this: (I used the font `mtpro2`.)

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}    
\begin{tabular}{p{8cm}l}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{(a)~$\left( \frac{81}{16}\right)^{-0.25}\times \left( \frac{8}{27}\right) ^{-\frac{2}{3}}\times (0.25)^{-2.5}+\left(\sqrt{243\sqrt{3}}\right)^{\frac{1}{11}}\times (\sqrt{3})^{-1}=?$} \\
    (b)~$\sqrt[3]{a^{\frac{9}{2}}\sqrt{a^{-3}}}\div \sqrt{\sqrt[3]{a^{-7}}\cdot \sqrt[3]{a}}=?$ & (c)~$(5+2\sqrt{6})^{2000}\cdot (5-2\sqrt{6})^{1999}$ \\
    (d)~$\sqrt[a-b]{x^{\frac{b+c}{c-a}}}\sqrt[b-c]{x^{\frac{c+a}{a-b}}}\sqrt[c-a]{ x^{\frac{a+b}{b-c}}}=?$  &(e)~$(x^{\frac{2}{3}}+x^{-\frac{2}{3}}+1)(x^{\frac{2}{3}}-x^{-\frac{2}{3}})(x-x^{-1})^{-1}=?$
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

How can I make the superscript higher and a little bigger? For example, the orangle part in (d). I've tried throwing `\displaystyle` in the sub formula in `\sqrt{}`, but it wasn't lift up much. By the way, I use `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}` to lengthen the lineskip in my `tabular` environment. Is my method good enough? Is there another proper way to do the same thing?

Comment: Is `x^{(b+c)/(c-a)}` an option?

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes In Asia, it is rarely to write fraction like this, especially in the college textbook. So a true fraction is necessary.

Comment: How about `x^{\nicefrac{(b+c)}{c-a}}` (from package [`nicefrac`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nicefrac?lang=en)) then? (I actually use a simple macro for a similar slanted but vertically offset fraction, mainly inline).

Comment: @Chris H Do I need to include some package? I can't compile.

Comment: @ChrisH Thanks. I've tested. It is a cool package. But I still need a tradition vertical fraction.

Comment: not a duplicate, but the method used of inserting a `\phantom` subscript could apply here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123946/579

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While this approach does not increase the size of the superscript font, it does raise the scripted fraction, by using `x\strut^{\frac{b+c}{c-a}}` instead of `x^{\frac{b+c}{c-a}}`, which places the superscript relative to a `\strut` instead of an `x`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}    
\begin{tabular}{p{8cm}l}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{(a)~$\left( \frac{81}{16}\right)^{-0.25}\times \left( \frac{8}{27}\right) ^{-\frac{2}{3}}\times (0.25)^{-2.5}+\left(\sqrt{243\sqrt{3}}\right)^{\frac{1}{11}}\times (\sqrt{3})^{-1}=?$} \\
    (b)~$\sqrt[3]{a^{\frac{9}{2}}\sqrt{a^{-3}}}\div \sqrt{\sqrt[3]{a^{-7}}\cdot \sqrt[3]{a}}=?$ & (c)~$(5+2\sqrt{6})^{2000}\cdot (5-2\sqrt{6})^{1999}$ \\
    (d)~$\sqrt[a-b]{x\strut^{\frac{b+c}{c-a}}}\sqrt[b-c]{x\strut^{\frac{c+a}{a-b}}}\sqrt[c-a]{ x\strut^{\frac{a+b}{b-c}}}=?$  &(e)~$(x^{\frac{2}{3}}+x^{-\frac{2}{3}}+1)(x^{\frac{2}{3}}-x^{-\frac{2}{3}})(x-x^{-1})^{-1}=?$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, here it is without the `\strut`s

[image]

Comment: Wow. It seems to be what I want. Can you explain more on the mechanism of `\strut`? I mean what is this command designed for? :)

Comment: @Eric `\strut` (not `\struct`) is a zero-width entity that vertically spans exactly one complete line height and depth.  All normal text will otherwise fit within the vertical footprint of a `\strut`.  If some stacked in-line construction exceeds the height  or depth of the `\strut`, the document line spacing will become irregular, since room must be made to accommodate the extra height/depth.  The height plus depth of a `\strut` equals exactly the value of `\baselineskip`.

Comment: @Eric For someghing more visual, a `\strut` is a zero-width version of this: `\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\baselineskip}`.  Try setting that in a line of text to see it relative to surrounding text.

Comment: I'm typesetting a Chinese document, so my line spacing is big(I set `\linespread{1.6}`). When I use `\strut` in math mode, the exponent part will be lift too up. How can I modify it? (See the middle root in http://imgur.com/a/FsiNi)

Comment: @Eric you can `\newcommand\mystrut{\rule{0pt}{10pt}}` and use `\mystrut` instead of `\strut`, while varying the height of `\mystrut` (here chosen as `10pt`) to suit your needs.  You can add depth to the strut, if needed, with the syntax `\rule[<depth>]{0pt}{<height+depth>}`

Answer (score 3):

How about just `x^{^{\frac{b+c}{c-a}}}`?

Comment: Clever option but it makes the superscript much smaller.

Comment: Very clever @Werner.