# equation beauty?

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

```
\begin{equation}
I_D=I_{S}\left(e^{\tfrac{q(V+IR_s)}{nN_{ms}N_skT_c}}-1\right)
\end{equation}
```

Hi, in this equation my number 'e' lost its position and turn an ordinary number. I want superscripts to go higher and turn this equation normal.

thank you.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 15):

The following code shows four ways of creating this equation:

1. Unchanged from your question (for comparison).
2. Following [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361429/103046), I inserted a `\strut` directly before the superscript such that the superscript is put to a higher position. Since in this example it is a very small effect, there is
3. with a `\Big.` instead of the `\strut`. One can also experiment with `\big.`, `\bigg.`, or `\Bigg.` (In the first version of this answer, I suggested to use `{\Large\strut}` which works but produces a warning `Command \Large invalid in math mode`.)
4. Personally, I would not try to write the exponent as an exponent, but rather use a functional notation of the exponential.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    I_D&=I_S\left(\mathrm{e}^{\tfrac{q(V+IR_s)}{nN_{ms}N_skT_c}}-1\right) \\
    I_D&=I_S\left(\mathrm{e}\strut^{\tfrac{q(V+IR_s)}{nN_{ms}N_skT_c}}-1\right) \\
    I_D&=I_S\left(\mathrm{e}\Big.^{\tfrac{q(V+IR_s)}{nN_{ms}N_skT_c}}-1\right) \\
    I_D&=I_S\left[\exp\left(\frac{q(V+IR_s)}{nN_{ms}N_skT_c}\right)-1\right]
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One note: I replaced `e` with `\mathrm{e}`. There are different opinions and language-specific traditions on how to print Euler's constant; you choose of course your preferred way.

Comment: That's not just an answer but a complete lesson. Thank you very much.

Comment: +1, especially for #4, although I would use `\biggl` and `\biggr` instead of `\left` and `\right`