# Modification of overrightarrow

Tags: superscripts, overset

I have a simple question... I want a modified version of `\overrightarrow` such that:

[image: what I want:]

So, the (n) is vertically aligned with the arrow. And this of course for every letter and symbol. The first line I make with

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
$\displaystyle \overrightarrow{a}^{(n)} \text{ and } \overrightarrow{A}^{(n)}$
\end{document}
```

The second line is made with paint (manually aligning the (n)'s)

Comment: I do not see any difference?!

Comment: In the second line, the (n) is vertically aligned with the arrow

Comment: Maybe search for "\raisebox".

Comment: I actually already did this, but this does not yield a generic solution... (as far as I could find)

Comment: Please provide code so we have something to work with.

Comment: I added some code in the post. I kindof assumed it was clear, haha :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just brace `\overright{a}`. However, I suggest a slimmer form of the arrows, because the default ones are really too big.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[old]{old-arrows}

\newcommand{\vect}[1]{{\varoverrightarrow{#1}}}

\begin{document}

$\vect{a}^{(n)}$ and $\vect{A}^{(n)}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the standard arrows, just remove the call to `old-arrows` and remove `var` from the definion of `\vect` to get

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I meant, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The idea comes from the answer of Steven B. Segletes here: [How can I move the superscript higher?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361427/how-can-i-move-the-superscript-higher), which suggest to use `\strut` and, in a comment, `\rule{0pt}{<dimen>}`. As I think this second solution is more interesting, I thought it appropriate to summarize it here:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\moveup}[1]{\rule{0pt}{#1pt}}
\begin{document}
 $\displaystyle \overrightarrow{a}\moveup{7.5}^{(n)} 
\text{ and } 
\overrightarrow{A}\moveup{10}^{(n)}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, as I use this on different types of symbols, the solution is not as generic as I would like, but the trick is a very nice one for my toolbox. Thank you!