# Vertical position of subscripts with commands

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts, braces

The answers to the questions [Differences in vertical positioning of superscripts and subscripts depending on grouping (`{ }`): Why? Caveats? Workarounds?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110214/differences-in-vertical-positioning-of-superscripts-and-subscripts-depending-on) and [{(x+y)}^2 or (x+y)^2?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104004/xy2-or-xy2) make it clear that one should use `(x+y)^2` over `{(x+y)}^2` to get a proper vertical position of the supscript.

However, what is the correct approach when one uses macros with use the brace-group and hence result in a different vertical position?
For example, the position of the subscript is different in `\mathrm{pr}_A` vs `pr_A`. How to get the text in roman font but at the same time keep the normal subscript position?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \( \mathrm{pr}_A \), \( pr_A \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of `\mathrm{pr}_A`, the subscript `A` is placed relative to a box that contains two letters, "pr". In contrast, in the case of `pr_A`, the subscript `A` is placed relative to a box that contains just `r`, not `pr`. The `pr` box has depth (i.e., material below the baseline), whereas the `r` box does not. When placing subscripts next to the box, TeX doesn't actually "know" what's *inside* the box, and hence it cannot "know" that it would actually be OK to place the subscript at a less-deep position. That's why the subscript is placed lower relative to "pr" than to "r".

Note that this holds for both upright and italic lettering.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \( \mathrm{pr}_A \)
    \( \mathit{pr}_A \) \ 
    \( \mathrm{p}\mathrm{r}_A \)
    \( pr_A \)
\end{document}
```

You also asked,

> How to get the text in roman font but at the same time keep the normal subscript position?

I suppose one could write `\mathrm{p}\mathrm{r}_A`. However, I wouldn't recommend it. Instead, I'd define `\pr` as a macro. E.g., if you load the `amsmath` package, you could write

```
\newcommand\pr{\smash[b]{pr}}
```

or

```
\newcommand\pr{\smash[b]{\mathrm{pr}}}  % for upright lettering of 'pr'
```

That way, the "pr" box has no depth and, in consequence, the subscript `A` won't be placed as low as if you wrote `\mathrm{pr}_A`.

Finally, if `\pr` is supposed to be a math operator, you should define this operator via the following instruction:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\pr}{\smash[b]{\mathrm{pr}}}
```

(`\DeclareMathOperator` is an instruction provided by the `amsmath` package.)