# Unaligned subscripts in latex formula

Tags: subscripts

I am trying to write the below formula in latex, but as you can see the subscript for sigma is not aligned with the one for mu. This is caused by the square in alpha. How can I align them?

[image]

UPDATE: the formula is in inline mode, like this

```
$q_{\phi}(z|x_i) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{\mu}_{z|x_i}, \mathbf{\sigma}_{z|x_i}^2\mathbf{I})$
```

UPDATE2: thanks to the link sent by @AndrewSwann, the vphantom command makes the trick!

```
$q_{\phi}(z|x_i) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{\mu}_{z|x_i}^{\vphantom{2}}, \mathbf{\sigma}_{z|x_i}^2\mathbf{I})$
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: easiest seems to be to add an empty superscript to the µ

Comment: This is tex's standard placement.  See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123945/15925 for a work around.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88362/15925 for more discussion.

Comment: @remco it aligs the subscripts, but it also adds a small apostopre at the top of mu

Comment: Is there a special meaning in the fact that `z` and `x_i` are normal weight in the left hand side and boldface in the right hand side? Can you please show the code you're using for that formula?

Comment: @user1571823 Not for me, using either PdfLatex or LuaLatex, with or without amsmath loaded. But as we don't have your code, hard to say more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a boldface mu, the command `\mathbf` is useless (and you get a normal weight mu, as you see).

A boldface mu can be obtained with `\bm{\mu}`. As said in the comments, sigma should not be boldface.

For aligning the subscripts, add an empty superscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

$q_{\phi}(z\mid x_i) \sim
\mathcal{N}(\bm{\mu}^{}_{z\mid x_i}, \sigma_{z\mid x_i}^2\mathbf{I})$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `\sigma^2` item on the right-hand side should *not* be rendered in **bold**. The full expression on the right is about a multivariate normal random variable with mean vector `\mu` and "scalar" (more precisely: diagonal, with all diagonal elements equal to one another) variance-covariance matrix. Thus, it's correct to write `\mathbf{I}` to denote the identity matrix, but `\sigma` should not be rendered in bold as well.

Comment: @Mico nice catch! i'll remove the bold command. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, here's a solution that employs LuaLaTeX and the `unicode-math` package.

Note that with `unicode-math` loaded, it's not necessary to load the `bm` package as well. The `\symbf` macro can be applied to both `\mu` and `I`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\[
q_{\phi}(z\mid x_i) \sim \mathcal{N}
(\symbf{\mu}^{}_{z\mid x_i}, 
\sigma_{z\mid x_i}^2\symbf{I})
\]
\end{document}
```